Zero weight loss from zero calorie drinks? Say it ain’t so
Shouldn't the title of the article be "Zero weight GAIN from zero calorie drinks? Say it ain’t so" instead of "Zero weight loss from zero calorie drinks? Say it ain’t so"  because people would expect to gain 0 weight from drinking 0 calorie drinks? Or am I missing something? Thank you!

Read the article, don't focus on the title, and the seemingly confusing message will become clear.

What the title "should" be is a matter of opinion and the personal style of the writer.  There's no error in English in the title.

Like Mari-Lou said, the first sentence of the second paragraph of the article you linked seems to directly answer the question you wrote. If it doesn't, please [edit] your question to explain why not, so answers can be more focused.

I didn't know most people actuslly believe drinking zero calorie beverages would lose weight. I thought the most it would do is to not gain more weight. Thus the question. I guess unlike most people, I have never had alright problem.

And because I didn't know and thought it was a language error of some kind, I am getting lots of negative points ...

No, it's saying that, contrary to expectation, drinking zero-calorie drinks does not actually cause weight loss.  Hence the "say it ain't so" -- people wish that it were not true.
The drinks would, of course, by themselves be expected to not change weight.  The studies cited refer to substituting zero-calorie drinks for drinks with calories, which would in itself cause weight loss.  However, it appears to cause other changes that prevent the loss.

Thank you all for your detailed explanations !

"Say it ain't so!" is a way to say "Please tell me that this isn't true!" -- they are begging the speaker to say they were joking or lying. It isn't the same as "It ain't/isn't so", which would be a direct claim that the original statement is in error.
In this context, it starts by stating the result of a study -- Zero calorie drinks do not improve weight loss results -- and then begs the study to say its own result was wrong.

The expression Say it an’t so is most closely associated with the Black Sox scandal of 1919 in which Shoeless Joe Jackson and others on the Chicago White Sox were thought to have “thrown” the World Series (intentionally lost in exchange for payment by mobsters). A famous piece in a Chicago newspaper, The Chicago Daily News, had the title “Say it ain’t so, Joe.”

Yep. Supposedly after a long questioning session, Joe came out to a crowd of onlookers and some small boy said the line, hoping his hero would deny the charges.
